# JAVA. JTABLE - How to count currently selected row(s)

Tags: java, jtable, row

I need to count selected row for removing multiple rows. Please help with the steps.

Example in the picture I want to delete/remove those selected rows at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @JFMeier sorry but I really don't know, but I can remove row 1by1 and it takes alot of clicks.

Comment: Is this question about _programming_?

Comment: Simply use `getSelectedRows()` to get the indexes of the selected rows.

Comment: yes. All I need is code like this. example : table.countSelectedRow().. like that

Comment: @Berger tnx :) Newbie here

Comment: You're welcome, have a look at the javadocs, it always helps : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Comment: Okay. thank you very much. You're a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

```
table.getSelectedRows().length
```